# What is the correct term for "growth rate of growth rate"?

Tags: statistics

Let's say a company had these monthly sales:

- Jan: $10$
- Feb: $15$
- Mar: $22.5$

The growth rate of sales would be:

- Jan: -
- Feb: $50$%
- Mar: $50$%

What is the correct term for the "growth rate of the growth rate of sales"? e.g.:

- Jan: -
- Feb: -
- Mar: $0$%

There are no results found when googling "growth rate of growth rate", which leads me to believe I don't know the common term for how to refer to things like this.

Comment: The analog for continuous change is easy. The growth rate is the derivative, the growth rate of the growth rate is the second derivative. They are like velocity (speed) and acceleration for moving bodies. For the discrete problem you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: What's wrong with "growth rate of the growth rate?"

Comment: Maybe you could vary the adjectives, such as with "rate of increase of the growth rate"?

Comment: Sales acceleration, maybe…?

Comment: ""rate of increase of the growth rate""  I personally would find growth rate of the growth rate easier to understand.

Comment: I would call it acceleration

Comment: it's called jerk.
eg: sales jerk

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an established term for the growth rate  of a growth rate. However I wanted to point out that the growth rate of a function is not its derivative; $e^{kx}$ should have the constant growth rate $k$ to match with OP's example $10(1.5^n)$. The correct quantity should be the 'logarithmic derivative',

$$ \frac{df}{d\log x} = \frac{f'}{f}.$$

This matches with what is meant by 'growth rate of the economy', for instance.

(edit) At a cursory glance, I can't find anything about 'growth rates of a growth rate', or 'second order growth rate' or anything like that. But there is a name for the 'simplest' kind of function with non-zero 'second order growth rate', in the sense below. Suppose we had the relationships between functions 
$$ f(x) = e^{g(x)}, \quad g'(x) = C_0e^{h(x)}$$
Thus, the growth rate of $f$ is $g'$, and the 'second order growth rate' of $f$ is $h'$. You have discovered the case where $h' = 0$. The next simplest case is when $h'$ is a non-zero constant, so that $h(x) = Hx+C_1$ for some constants $H\neq 0, C_1\in\mathbb R$. By recentering in $x$, $C_1 = 0$. Then $g(x) = C_3e^{Hx}+C_2$, which then gives us: 
$$f(x) = e^{\displaystyle C_3 e^{Hx }+C_2} = C_4 \exp(C_3\exp Hx )$$

That is, these are the [double exponential functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function).